# Need help on my tiny objective-c class design. How can I access my instance var?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am playing around with a tiny app that should store notes. The UI uses the master/detail view template.

My `MasterView` holds an instance of `NoteController` which in turn holds all notes stored in an array. Now I would like to save this array using `NSKeyArchiver`. I know there is the method `applicationDidEnterBackGround` implemented in `AppDelegate.m`.

But I can't call the instance method of `NoteController` from `AppDelegate`. Creating a new instance wouldn't work neither as then all data would be lost. So what's wrong with my design?

I hope it's clear what my problem is. Your help is greatly appreciated.

**Note.m:**

```
@interface Note : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *content;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate *creationDate;

@end
```

**NoteController.m:**

```
@class Note;
@interface NoteDataController : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *masterNoteList;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *dataFilePath; 

- (NSUInteger) countOfList;
- (Note*) objectInListAtIndex:(NSUInteger)theIndex;
- (void) addNote:(Note*)theNote;
- (void) removeNote:(NSUInteger)theIndex;
- (void) loadMasterList;
- (void) saveMasterList;

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My recommendation would be to save the `Note` as soon as possible. So if when you `-addNote:` that `Note` is fully realized (has title, content, etc.), then preserve it then and there in adding. As well, when you `-removeNote:`, you would also save your "notes file".

This simplifies matters, encapsulates all management of `Notes` to your `NoteController`, and avoids having to do things like somehow jack into the `AppDelegate`.

However, if this approach does not work for you, if what you do need is to save when the app enters the background, you could have your `NoteController` observe `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification` and the `NoteController` have a handler for that that end saves. Be mindful tho that saving upon entering the background may not be ideal: what if your app exits before that happens (e.g. it crashes)? also, switching to the background isn't a time to engage in lengthy tasks, so your `Note` preservation may not be best suited for this time.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the Singleton Pattern in your NoteController class, so you always keep in memory one instance of that class, and also, you will be able to access that from any class, including AppDelegate.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. So is 'viewWillDisappear' also called when the program get's into the background? (e.g. the home button gets pressed) The thing is, if I add the call to my save function within the MasterViewController's viewWillDisappear function then everytime the view changes i call the save method. But I only would like to call it on backgrounding the app

Comment: as the controller is not a subclass of UIViewController a `viewWillDisappear` will never be called. And I am quite sure that it wont be called even if it was in this case.

Answer (score 0):

[post a NSNotification](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Articles/Posting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000724-CEGJFDFG) by using the [`[NSNotifcationCenter defaultCenter]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) from `applicationDidEnterBackground:`.

There you must pay attention that your [task can be finished](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006786-CH3-SW20):

> Your implementation of this method has approximately five seconds to perform any tasks and return. If you need additional time to perform any final tasks, you can request additional execution time from the system by calling beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:. In practice, you should return from applicationDidEnterBackground: as quickly as possible. If the method does not return before time runs out your application is terminated and purged from memory.
>
> You should perform any tasks relating to adjusting your user interface before this method exits but other tasks (such as saving state) should be moved to a concurrent dispatch queue or secondary thread as needed. Because it's likely any background tasks you start in applicationDidEnterBackground: will not run until after that method exits, you should request additional background execution time before starting those tasks. In other words, first call beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler: and then run the task on a dispatch queue or secondary thread.

Let your controller [listen (register) to this notification](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Articles/Registering.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000723-CEGCCFID) and perform saving, if the notification is received.